# add_menu_page $positon of menu item in admin menu don't working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with this code:

```
function pims_create_admin_menu () {
  $icon_url = plugins_url('../icons/admin-menu-left-icon.png',__FILE__);
  add_menu_page('pims-home-panel', 'PIMŚ', 'manage_options','pims-menu-home' ,'pims_menu_homepage' ,$icon_url, 61); 
}
```

The position of item: 61 don't working. My item is displayed on the bottom of menu. I trying '61' and "61", but it still don't work

Comment: What do you mean `don't work`? What do you expect it to do?  FYI, this works perfectly - what other values have you tried than 61? Have you tried 1? 10? 20?

Comment: I expect the PIMŚ menu item to be displayed between the Appearence and Plugins items in the Wordpress administration menu. 1.10 or 20 also do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem.

Error line is: `add_action('admin_head','pims_create_admin_menu');`

I change admin_head to admin_menu and this fix the problem.